# SPARK: What is the most efficient way to take a KV pair and turn it into a typed dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, datastax-enterprise

Spark Newbie here attempting to use Spark to do some ETL and am having trouble finding a clean way of unifying the data into the destination scheme.

I have multiple dataframes with these keys / values in a spark context (streaming)

Dataframe of long values:

```
entry---------|long---------
----------------------------
alert_refresh |1446668689989
assigned_on   |1446668689777
```

Dataframe of string values

```
entry---------|string-------
----------------------------
statusmsg     |alert msg
url           |http:/svr/pth
```

Dataframe of boolean values

```
entry---------|boolean------
----------------------------
led_1         |true
led_2         |true
```

Dataframe of integer values:

```
entry---------|int----------
----------------------------
id            |789456123
```

I need to create a unified dataframe based on these where the key is the fieldName and it maintains the type from each source dataframe. It would look something like this:

```
id-------|led_1|led_2|statusmsg|url----------|alert_refresh|assigned_on
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
789456123|true |true |alert msg|http:/svr/pth|1446668689989|1446668689777
```

***What is the most efficient way to do this in Spark?***

BTW - I tried doing a matrix transform:

```
val seq_b= df_booleans.flatMap(row => (row.toSeq.map(col => (col, row.toSeq.indexOf(col))))) 
 .map(v => (v._2, v._1)) 
 .groupByKey.sortByKey(true) 
 .map(._2) 

val b_schema_names = seq_b.first.flatMap(r => Array(r)) 
val b_schema = StructType(b_schema_names.map(r => StructField(r.toString(), BooleanType, true)))
val b_data = seq_b.zipWithIndex.filter(._2==1).map(_._1).first() 
val boolean_df = sparkContext.createDataFrame(b_data, b_schema)
```

Issue: Takes 12 seconds and .sortByKey(true) does not always sort values last